# Assigning event handlers to objects with variables in a loop

Tags: java, android, events

I'm having trouble programatically adding event handlers to table rows. Since I have to declare the variable as final, all the event handlers always only use the last assigned value. I have no idea how to fix this. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    public void Refresh()
{
    Looper.prepare();
    final Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Refreshen...";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    try {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://www.nu.nl/"));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            String responseString = out.toString();
            String[] lines = responseString.split("\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
            {
                if(lines[i].contains("<li class=\"  \" data-vr-contentbox=\"articlelist"))
                {
                    final String url = stripSpaces(lines[i + 2].replace("<a href=\"", "").replace("\" class=\"trackevent\" >", ""));
                    final String title = stripSpaces(lines[i + 6].replace("<span class=\"title\">", "").replace("</span>", ""));
                    final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
                            row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            TextView view = new TextView(context);
                            view.setText(title);
                            row.addView(view);
                            tl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, News.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("url", url);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                            tl.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } else {
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble [...]" What trouble?

Comment: SeelenVirtuose I explained that in the sentences afterwards. Whatever button in the list I click, it always points to the last added value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, turns out I was setting the onClick event to the whole table instead of the row...